# Summing up total price in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to somehow sum up totalPrice of products in my order.

My `order` object contains `2 properties (datePlaced, userId)` and `items` object which contains `2 properties (quantity, totalPrice)` and `product` object with some properties but it doesn't matter.

I have order-details component where I display details of order so `name` of product, `quantity` of product and `totalPrice` of product.

`totalPrice = price * quantity`

So when I order for example one `tomato ($10)` and two `apples (2x $10)` I see two rows with `totalPrice` for `tomato` and `totalPrice` for `apple`

I want to sum up all these `totalPrice` properties in one property `total`.
I tried taking `order` object and loop through every `order.item.totalPrice` property but I cannot take `order` object in my **order-details.component.ts**. I subscribe to `getOrder` function which take me `order` object from database but I cannot asign this array to my property `order[]` in my **order-details.component.ts**. I got `undefined` and I know why so please do not explain me this issue.

I have also model class `order.ts` where I initialize all the properties of my order

**order.ts**

```
export class Order {
    datePlaced: number;
    items: any[];
    total: number; // create total which I want to have sum of totalPrice (below property)

    constructor(public userId: String, public shopping: any, shoppingCart: ShoppingCart) {
        this.datePlaced = new Date().getTime();
        this.items = shoppingCart.items.map(i => {
            return {
                product: {
                    title: i.title,
                    imageUrl: i.imageUrl,
                    price: i.price,
                    discount: i.discount
                },
                quantity: i.quantity,
                totalPrice: i.totalPrice // I want to loop this property and sum up

            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: What about using reduce ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: totalPrice: i.reduce( (a,b) => (a + b.totalPrice),0 )

Comment: `total: i.reduce( (a,b) => (a + b.totalPrice),0 )` and I've got an error `Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'ShoppingCartItem'`

Comment: Ok -> shoppingCart.items.reduce( (a, b) => (a, b.totalPrice),0)

Comment: shoppingCart.items is your array of items, you want to sum all totalPrice values for each item in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your array like i have some basic example below.

```
{"item_selected":[{"quantity":1,"item_id":"5ad4871814e95544ef10e61a","item_name":"Cookies and Cream","selected_size":"Large","item_price":20.5,"_id":"5b190d2a6346b714af7c4d1a"}],"_id":"5b190d2a6346b714af7c4d1b","grossTotal":20.5}
```

This Kind of array help to push all the item in the item_selected array and grossTotal will be calculated each item_price of item_selected. Please Multiply with quantity then update the grossTotal.

Comment: I don't know exactly if I follow your idea, is there simpler solution of my problem? I just want to sum up my values (can I do it in my HTML template?) I don't want to change my database structure